# All tweets from Blogger says data:blog.metaDescription

Tags: twitter, metadata, blogger

I've been trying to update my dead blog Devilish Heels but I'm running into a problem with Twitter. New tweets and old tweets all say data:blog.metaDescription. I don't know much about Twitter, and can't seem to find a way to fix or remove that portion.

I have spent five hours searching the net and adding one twitter card after another to my blog with my blog and twitter info, but nothing changes. (Pretty sure I need to reset template at this point) I don't know what else to do. I tried all the different solutions from others who had similar issues but nothing is working for me.

[My Blog](https://shoegallery.blogspot.com/)

[My Twitter](https://twitter.com/DevilishHeelz)

Comment: Provide your template head code

Comment: Here is the header:

Comment: Add all the code between `<head>` and `</head>` tags to your question